# Year to Date calculation SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
oGroup     oDate          oValue
--------------------------------
A          2014-01-01     10
A          2014-01-02     20
A          2014-02-01     10
A          2014-02-02     10
A          2014-03-01     10
A          2014-04-01     30
A          2014-05-01     10
B          2014-01-01     5
```

Then I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _spTest
    (@oMonth int, @oYear int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        oGroup, oDate, oValue
    FROM 
        oTable
    WHERE 
        DATEPART(MONTH, oDate) = @oMonth 
        AND DATEPART(YEAR, oDate) = @oYear
END
```

So if I put the parameter for @oMonth = 4 and @oYear = 2014. Then all records with month 4 (April) and year 2014 will show as a result.

My question is: I want to know the total of 'oValue' from the beginning of the year until the given value  with **the same parameter** as above stored procedure. How can I achieve this?

For example, if the @oMonth is 4, and the @oYear is 2014. Then the result should be `SUM` of `oValue` on January 2014 + `SUM` of `oValue` on February 2014 + `SUM` of `oValue` on March 2014 + `SUM` of `oValue` on April 2014

The result should be like this:

```
oGroup     oValue_SUM
---------------------
A          90
B          5
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Between` Operator to filter the records to start from Current Year. The Use `Sum aggregate` to find the total of `ovalue`

```
create table #test( oGroup   char(1),  oDate    date,      oValue int)
insert #test values
('A'          ,'2014-01-01' ,    10),
('A'          ,'2014-01-02' ,    20),
('A'          ,'2014-02-01'  ,   10),
('A'          ,'2014-02-02' ,    10),
('A'          ,'2014-03-01' ,    10),
('A'          ,'2014-04-01' ,    30),
('A'          ,'2014-05-01' ,    10),
('B'          ,'2014-01-01' ,    5)

DECLARE @oMonth INT=4,
        @oYear  INT=2014

SELECT oGroup,
       Sum(oValue) Total
FROM   #test
WHERE  Datepart(MONTH, oDate) BETWEEN 1 AND @oMonth
       AND Datepart(YEAR, oDate) = @oYear
GROUP  BY oGroup,
          Year(odate)
```

**Output :**

```
oGroup  Total
------  -----
A       90
B       5
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _spTest
(@oMonth int, @oYear int)
AS
BEGIN
      SELECT 
          oGroup
          , max(oDate)
          , sum(oValue)
      FROM 
          oTable
      WHERE 
          DATEPART(MONTH, oDate) <= @oMonth 
          AND DATEPART(YEAR, oDate) = @oYear
      GROUP BY
          oGroup
END
```

(Not sure if you want it grouped by `oGroup` or not, or what you want to do with the `oDate` column)